# Python TypeError: Required argument 'offset' (pos 1) not found

Tags: python, django, django-models

I get an error `TypeError: Required argument 'offset' (pos 1) not found` when i instantiated an object form models class: `users` like `a = users()` this class has dynamic attributes created from a list `service_data` using `vars()` function.

```
 class users(models.Model):
      for i, j in zip(config.service_data[0], config.service_data[1]):
          vars()[i] = CrudAPI.create_db_field(j)
```

And this is create_db_field method code:

```
def create_db_field(test):
      if (test == "char50"):
          return models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
      if (test == "text"):
          return models.TextField(blank=True)
      if (test == "date"):
          return models.DateField(blank=True)
      if (test == "datetime"):
          return models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.timezone, blank=True)
      if (test == "number"):
          return models.FloatField(blank=True)
```

and this is my list used to create those attributes dynamically:

`service_data=[["username","password"],[],["email","password"]]`

```
tarting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
[13/Apr/2019 11:33:59] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 17234
[13/Apr/2019 11:34:02] "GET /login/ HTTP/1.1" 200 1382
True
Internal Server Error: /login_/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\softs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "F:\softs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 126, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "F:\softs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 124, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "F:\projects\PycharmProjects\roottic\root\views.py", line 61, in login_
    a = users()
  File "F:\softs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 459, in __init__
    val = field.get_default()
  File "F:\softs\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 798, in get_default
    return self._get_default()
TypeError: Required argument 'offset' (pos 1) not found
[13/Apr/2019 11:34:04] "POST /login_/ HTTP/1.1" 500 75786
```

I don't understand what the wrong with it

Comment: Please add the *full* traceback.

Comment: The `service_data` will, with this `zip` function result in an *empty* loop.

Comment: service_data is  not empty list

Comment: that's correct, but the `zip` function will `zip(["username","password"],[])`, and thus that results in an empty iterable.

Comment: i filled them but the same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `create_db_field` method, you define the option for "datetime" as returning a DateTimeField with the default of `datetime.timezone`. That is what will be called when you create a new instance of `users` without setting that field. But `timezone()` is a function which expects a parameter, `offset`, which you aren't passing.

I suspect you didn't mean to use that function from the standard datetime module, but the Django function `timezone.now` instead:

```
from django.utils import timezone
...

    return models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now, blank=True)
```

(I must say, unrelated to your error, this is all a very strange thing to do; what's the point? Django models reflect tables in databases, why try and define them dynamically?)